# странный синтаксис

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, c++11

очень неясно как работает данный код

```
int a[] = {4, 5, 2, 3, 1};
int i = *a;

for (;i;)
{
    std::cout << i--[a];  // не понятная строчка
}

//  output: 1325
```

к чему тут декремент применяется???

ну, очевидно, что к переменной `i`, раз цикл завершается.

Но как тогда происходят обращения к элементам массива ? почему нет ошибки компиляции ?

Впервый раз в жизни встречаю подобный код

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Декремент тут применяется `i` хотя бы просто потому, что больше он в данной записи ни к чему применяться не может - справа от него стоит лексема `[`, которая началом выражения-операнда быть никак не может.

Тема же эквивалентности `a[i]` и `i[a]` заезжена донельзя. Выражение `x[y]` по определению является лишь сокращенной формой записи для `*(x + y)`. Один операнд должен быть массивом/указателем, а другой - целочисленным или enum значением. Причем ограничений на порядок указания операндов не накладывается. Поэтому ваше `i--[a]` эквивалентно `*(i-- + a)`  эквивалентно `*(a + i--)` и эквивалентно `a[i--]`. Никакой "ошибки компиляции" тут нет.

Вышесказанное относится именно и только к *встроенному* оператору `[]`. Для перегруженного оператора `[]` порядок аргументов фиксирован, то есть для выражения `x[y]` будет рассматриваться только перегруженный вариант `x.operator[](y)`, но не `y.operator[](x)`.

Comment: ну ок яснее стало, просто я редко использую в своей практике подобные извращённые способы доступа к элементам массива

Comment: @ampawd: А их и не надо использовать. Пишите по-человечески - массив снаружи, индекс внутри. Можно предположить, что какая-нибудь generic техника может завязываться на возможность менять местами операнды (что-то как-будто вертится на краешке памяти), но и там это вряд ли критически необходимо.

Comment: А нет ли разницы в _порядке_ вычисления (для случая, если `a` и `i` — выражения с побочными эффектами)?

Comment: @VladD: Никакого взаимного упорядочения (sequencing), между вычислениями операндов встроенного оператора `[]` не вводится, т.е. все буквально эквивалентно `*(... + ...)` варианту. Т.е. разницы нет.

Answer (score 9):

Оператор индексирования относится к классу постфиксных операторов. Он определяется следующим образом (стандарт C++, раздел 5.2.1 Subscripting)

> 1 A **postﬁx expression** followed by an expression in square brackets is
>   a postﬁx expression.

То есть за постфиксным выражением следует выражение в квадратных скобках.

В этом выражении

```
i--[a]
```

`i--` - это оператор пост-декремента, который относится к классу постфиксных выражений. Итак, имеется

```
    i--                   [a]
     |                     |
постфиксное выражение   выражение в квадратных скобках
```

Так что с точки зрения синтаксиса данное выражение совершенно корректное.

Далее в той же самой цитате из стандарта имеется продолжение

> 1 ... One of the expressions shall have the type “array of T” or
>   “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration or
>   integral type. The result is of type “T.” The type “T” shall be a
>   completely-deﬁned object type.64 The expression E1[E2] is identical
>   (by deﬁnition) to *((E1)+(E2))

из которого следует, что одно из выражений должно быть либо массивом, либо указателем, а другое выражение - перечислением или целочисленным типом. Какое из этих двух выражений какой должен иметь тип не существенно, так как по определению выражение `E1[E2]` эквивалентно выражению `*((E1) + (E2))`.

В С++ вы можете написать даже более вычурную конструкцию, добавив знак плюс перед именем массива. Например,

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    int i = 0;

    std::cout <<  i++[+a] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

В C такая конструкция `i++[+a]` не будет компилироваться, так как в C в отличии от C++ нельзя применять унарный плюс к имени массива.

В C++ пользователь также может перегружать оператор индексирования для списка инициализации в фигурных скобках. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <numeric>

int main() 
{
    struct A
    {
        long long int operator []( std::initializer_list<int> l ) const
        {
            return std::accumulate( l.begin(), l.end(), 0ll );
        }
    };

    std::cout <<  A()[{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
55
```

Comment: а что даёт унарный плюс перед именем массива ? какой тут семантический смысл ?

Comment: тоесть второй `sizeof` выведет размер `int` а хотите сказать?

Comment: @ampawd Второй sizeof выведет размер указателя.